# MySQL JSON_SEARCH with Boolean value not working

Tags: mysql, json

I am facing an issue with MySQL JSON_SEARCH function, which does not support the boolean value search.

Please refer this SQL:
https://rextester.com/DYLPJG17389

Here is database schema:

```
create table if not exists superheroes (
    name varchar(32),
    attributes JSON
    );

insert into superheroes 
values ('Batman', '{"dead": "false", "orphan": true, "billionaire": "true", "goodboy" : "true"}');

SELECT JSON_SEARCH(attributes, 'all', 'true')
FROM superheroes
WHERE name = 'Batman';

drop table superheroes;
```

Right now result has:
`["$.goodboy", "$.billionaire"]`

I need my result should have `"$.orphan"`
I can't replace `true` with `"true"` as JSON data are coming from the external source.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: Please add the relevant details from the link you have provided in case the link is no longer available in future

Comment: just quote **true** after **orphan** as `"orphan": "true"` within the json column. Refer [this](https://rextester.com/TUQUN49430)

Comment: @Vicky, You mean to say you **can't** replace *true* with *"true"* ? Because you post says you can replace. If that is the case you have already got the answer from Barbaros Özhan.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy Sorry for typo mistake, I can't replace as data coming from an external source. Also, this is just a small node of actual JSON data.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON_SEARCH` will work only for Strings as the [**Docmentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) says

> ```
> JSON_SEARCH(json_doc, one_or_all, search_str[, escape_char[, path] ...])
> ```
>
> Returns the path to the given string within a JSON document

Also JSON values should be enclosed in double quote for that to a string

> JSON value can be a string in [**double quotes**](http://www.json.org/), or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array

So in your case one possible solution could be converting the Boolean `true` to String `"true"`. If you cannot replace manually, you can use `JSON_REPLACE` to change `true` to `"true"`. Since you already know the `key` for which you have to change the value use below query to get your desired result.

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH((JSON_REPLACE(attributes,'$.orphan',"true")), 'all', 'true') 
FROM superheroes
WHERE name = 'Batman';
```

[**Check your Demo here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=800d9c7ae9e3a233b46d75aeecacf64c)

***OUTPUT:***

```
["$.orphan", "$.goodboy", "$.billionaire"]
```

**Update**

If your key `orphan` contains both `true` and `false`, you can just replace only the true value using `case` and `JSON_CONTAINS` as below.

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(( CASE 
                       WHEN JSON_CONTAINS(attributes, "true", '$.orphan') = 1 
                     THEN 
                       JSON_REPLACE(attributes, '$.orphan', "true") 
                       ELSE attributes 
                     END ), 'all', 'true') 
FROM   superheroes 
WHERE  NAME = 'Batman';
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ad072737a94592bc6430028a59524b6)

Comment: JSON_REPLACE will replace all occurrences '$.orphan' to '"true"', in case of the array of value, some '$.orphan' with false will also replace will '"true"'.
Is that correct?

Comment: @Vicky, Correct. But we can avoid that using `case` and `JSON_CONTAINS`. I have updated my answer.